# Help with performance: SUBQUERY vs JOIN 

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery

this is my problem:

**SUBQUERY `2.7 secs`**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 
  item_id

  FROM
    mtrt_items_searches

  WHERE
    search_id IN (      
            SELECT 
            SQL_NO_CACHE
                search_id
                FROM
                    mtrt_searches_groups
                WHERE 
                    client_id =1
                GROUP BY 
                    search_id

        )

    LIMIT 0,350000

+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mtrt_items_searches  | index | NULL          | search_id | 12      | NULL  | 367362 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | mtrt_searches_groups | ref   | client_id     | client_id | 4       | const |     13 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
```

**The subquery alone takes 0.0009 secs to return the following data, and replacing the subquery with this data, the query runs in `0.2 secs`:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    item_id

    FROM
        mtrt_items_searches
    WHERE
        search_id IN (
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35
        )

    LIMIT 0,350000

+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mtrt_items_searches | index | search_id     | search_id | 12      | NULL | 367362 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
```

**Finally the JOIN running in `0.4 secs`:**

```
   SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
        r.item_id

        FROM
            mtrt_items_searches r
        INNER JOIN 
            mtrt_searches_groups sg 
                ON r.search_id =sg.search_id
        WHERE 
            sg.client_id =1
        GROUP BY 
            r.item_id

        LIMIT 0,350000

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys       | key       | key_len | ref                    | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sg    | ref  | search_id,client_id | client_id | 4       | const                  |    13 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref  | search_id           | search_id | 4       | clubr_new.sg.search_id | 26240 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**I'm trying to do either the subquery or the join in `0.2 secs`. Is it possible?**

Comment: Restart MySql and run the 2nd query - with the hard coded IDs - again. It will take closer to 5 seconds. (`SQL_NO_CACHE` doesn't take the OS file cache into account)

Comment: try doing selects and specifying table names. In the first select(with the subquery) i see you use the same column names, and i'm not sure how they get resolved in the subquery. Not sure how this would affect things though

Comment: How many records are we talking about here?

Comment: @Doug-Kress About 350000

Comment: @the-scrum-meister I've tested. Same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN item_id
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT search_id
    FROM mtrt_searches_groups
    WHERE client_id = 1
) JOIN mtrt_items_searches USING(search_id)
LIMIT 0,350000
```

Comment: Great. `0.2 secs`. Didn't know that mysql actually do not execute the subquery first without STRAIGHT_JOIN. So, subqueries is faster then joins?

Comment: @Doug-Kress and "The Scrum Meister": Without STRAIGHT_JOIN runs the same way actually. The main change come from the subquery location.

Answer (score 1):

try and add the following indexes

```
mtrt_items_searches(search_id,item_id)
mtrt_searches_groups(client_id, search_id)
```

Comment: look at the EXPLAIN for the last SELECT;)

Comment: @Downvoter please leave a comment. As you can see from the `EXPLAIN` output there is no **composite** index on `search_id,item_id`

Comment: @The why would he need a composite index for a direct search? composite indexes are used when both keys are searched simultaneously.. _In the last EXPLAIN, all items use an indexed column_, and the result returns exactly the number of rows requested in the LIMIT statement.. everything seems ok there. Maybe there are simlpy too many rows for the server/network to handle them

Comment: +1 Thank you! I've changed this. I'm still trying to achieve at last `0.2 secs`. Look again.

Comment: @Keyne how did the change affect the results?

Comment: @Quamis The join is faster now. From `1.8` to `0.4 secs`. Also the subquery, from `5` to `2.7 secs`

Answer (score -1):

Mmmm i don't think so. The Subqueries are too slow, sadly the fastest way is using the data directly.