# Is there reduced overhead when using multiple statements in the same query for mysql?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if I can reduce the overhead by sending multiple statements in the same query to the database. Is this possible?

I am currently sending the queries one by one and would like to send a batch several at the same time (all in all I'm sending 2k or so queries)

They are all select queries

Comment: The answers are "not really," "yes kind of," and "it depends." :)  What kind of queries?  INSERT?  UPDATE?  SELECT?  DELETE?

Comment: They are all select queries (edited main)

Comment: For a [mass] UPDATE/INSERT, the bigger issue is usually *correctly using* transactions. However, each query requires a *round trip* which might be "expensive" for networks with latencies over a few milliseconds or so: in this case multiple statements per query reduce the individual roundtrip latency overheads. To put it in perspective, with a 50ms latency, only 20 queries *max* can be processed per second. In any case, if there is a suspected performance issue, the first step is to find out *where*.

Comment: "2k" =~ 2,000 queries?  Against the same table, or different tables?  Fetching one row at a time?

Comment: Yes, 2000. Against several joined tables (60 different ones or so, which ones are joined specificly varies a bit)

Comment: What's your application environment?  PHP? Perl? Python?

Comment: node.js using Node-mysql-libmysqlclient.

Answer (score 1):

I used batch inserts when working with Grails and MySQL, and the time for inserts was reduced by a factor of 100! (I processed about 50 inserts at once with batch processing) So I can definitely say batch inserts save a lot of time.

I am not sure how much of this post can help you, but here [Help with performance: SUBQUERY vs JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117686/help-with-performance-subquery-vs-join)

The way you join tables could also be a major issue on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Batching SQL operations can definitely improve overall speed. For small queries, the slowest part is often establishing a DB connection. This is an expensive step, regardless of the SQL query itself. You can reduce this overhead by reducing the number of times you have to create and destroy these DB connections.

Comment: That's true, although the round-trip time from the application server to the database server can also be the biggest time-eater if the two are geographically separated.

Comment: The DB connection is persistent between my queries I think

Comment: All these poor languages without standard connection pooling. Makes me sad. In any case, for this question, the connection will (or should) only be established once in either case.

Comment: I will soon have my own implementaton of connection pooling however